# XGBoost module not found in site-packages. Imports but doesn't work. (mac OS)

Tags: python-3.x, macos, xgboost

I was able to install xgboost on my mac and have it so that I can import the module without any errors. However I cannot use it. When I try to import `XGBRegressor`. I get the following error :

> cannot import name 'XGBRegressor' from 'xgboost' (unknown location).

Some of the support for this type of problem says that there may be more than one xgboost location, and that python is selecting the incorrect xgboost, however I have not been able to find how to fix this problem.

When I print the `xgboost.__file__` location, it returns 'None'. However I know its in the site-packages folder in my python path.

I have python 3.9

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this.

```
conda install -c conda-forge xgboost=0.6a2
```

Then, restart Spyder and re-run!